# This c program gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am write a c program to test structure pass into a function

but it give segmentation fault ,why?

Please give me the solution to solve this issue?

The code i am tried is given below,

```css
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#define GRAYSCALE
void set_pixel_data(int depth, void   *p);
   
struct pixel_gray { char m; };
struct pixel_color { char r; char g; char b; };


int main()
{
struct pixel_gray  pg;
struct pixel_color pc;
#ifdef GRAYSCALE
 set_pixel_data( 1, &pg);
#else
 set_pixel_data( 3, &pc);
#endif

 return(0);
}
void set_pixel_data(int depth, void   *p)
{

switch(depth)
{
struct pixel_gray* p1;
case 1:
p1=(struct pixel_gray*)p;
strcpy(p1->m,"s");                                   //here is the problem
//printf("%s",p1->m);


    break;
case 3:
    printf("33");
    break;
default:
    printf("nothing he he ");
    break;
}

}
```

Comment: `strcpy(p1->m,"s");` are you claiming your compiler does *not* warn you about that call? ? you're sending a `char` to an argument that expects `char*` . Turn up your warnings and treat them as errors.  I'm not necessarily convinced you even need `strcpy` here, nor `%s` printing on the subsequent line.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct pixel_gray { char m; };
p1=(struct pixel_gray*)p;
strcpy(p1->m,"s");
```

`p1->m` is a variable of type `char`. The `strcpy` function expects a valid pointer to a buffer of at least the length of the string passed as the second argument to `strcpy` including zero terminating character, in this case a pointer to a buffer of at least two characters.

Because you pass a `char` value, the value is cast to a pointer, which is (most probably) an invalid pointer value. As `strcpy` tries to dereference that pointer value, undefined behavior happens which on your platform gives a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), which is literally a condition that is raised on invalid memory access.

If you want to assign a single character just assign it to `p1->m`:

```
p1->m = 's';
```

Alternatively, if you want to store the string `"s"` inside `p1->m` variable, change the declarations of the struct member `m` of structure `pixel_gray` to a char buffer of at least the length of two characters.

```
struct pixel_gray {
    char m[2];
};
```